# Using `.noConflict()` when loading jQuery asynchronously in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a project, where I have to load jQuery dynamically like this:

```
(function() {

  var scriptOnLoad = function() {
    jQuery.noConflict();

    // Do my stuff here
  };

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
  script.onload = scriptOnLoad;
  script.onreadystatechange = function () { 
  if ( script.readyState == 'loaded' || script.readyState == 'complete' ) 
    scriptOnLoad(); 
  };
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```

The site also uses Prototype, which should be covered by using `.noConflict()`.

However in IE9 it sometimes happens that some other JS code (not mine and I can't control it) using the variable `$` fails, because it is still set to jQuery instead of Prototype's function.

I assume it's a timing problem and that IE executes other JavaScript between the loading of jQuery and the executing of the `readystatechange` event handler. Can anyone confirm if this is the case?

What could be the solution to this? The only thing I can think of is to use my own modified copy of jQuery that doesn't overwrite `$` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate jquery and jQuery.noConflict(); in one single file and load this without the need of script loaded handler.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure but you can try initializing jquery in a variable like $j = jQuery.noConflict() and use $j for your code.

Comment: That's not the problem. The other code that uses $ gets jQuery when it expects prototype.